# Outlook 2010 rules to copy sent items to a public folder not working (permissions and manual drag/drop OK)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange, exchange-2010, public-folders

We have hosted Exchange with Intermedia. We have a POP account that a bunch of users send (but don't receive) emails from, and a public folder that a bunch of users store emails in so that others can view them. For a long time, we've configured each user's Outlook (2010, 7 pro 64bit) to use a rule to copy all sent items from the POP account to a particular subfolder under the main public folder.

This works on all computers except those deployed recently (nothing in our initial configuration has changed except a re-download of the Office binary from Microsoft; same version and everything. We got rid of the old one).

On recently-deployed computers, every time that rule runs (every time something is sent through the POP account), an **error appears saying "Could not copy message to Sent folder"** ("Sent" is the name of the subfolder that messages are headed for). Why is this occurring?

Things I have tried:

- Verifying that each user affected has permissions on that folder. They do; everyone has either "Owner" or "Publishing Editor" perms.
- Verifying that each user affected can manually drag/drop/delete/update emails in that folder. They all can.
- Re-propagating all permissions on the public folder. Tried it twice. Same result.
- Re-installing OS/office/everything with totally stock settings. No change.
- Contacting Intermedia (Exchange hosting provider). They said that the problem has to be on our end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be happening because our hosting providers had configured size limitations/quotas on public folders wrong. Subfolders beneath the parent public folder had much smaller size quotas than the master folder, causing unpredictable behavior like this. Furthermore, there had apparently been a ongoing (unspecified) issue with public folder replication between geographically distant servers.

This is unlikely to be the case for anyone else.